# Adding custom operations with hook_entity_operation()

Tags: entities, 9

I'm trying to add a custom entity operation to taxonomy terms of a specific vocabulary.

I've found documentation on using hook_entity_operation() to add the operation, and that works, but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Here's the hook implementation:

```
function nm_target_entity_operation(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $operations = [];
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'taxonomy_term' && $entity->vid->getString() == 'data-source') {
    $operations['import'] = [
      'title' => t('Re-import'),
      'url' => // what goes here?
      'weight' => 50,
    ];
  }
  return $operations;
}
```

If I want to have a confirmation page at /taxonomy/term/{taxonomy_term}/import, what do I put in the URL property and what kind of class should that route point at?

I took a look at Entity Clone module as that's the only contribute module we use that implements that hook, but that does complicated things with link templates that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation of what the array returned by `hook_entity_operation()` contains is explained in the documentation for [`EntityListBuilderInterface::getOperations()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityListBuilderInterface.php/function/EntityListBuilderInterface%3A%3AgetOperations/9).

> - title: The localized title of the operation.
> - url: An instance of \Drupal\Core\Url for the operation URL.
> - weight: The weight of this operation.

`'url'` is simply the URL for the page executing that operation.

There are 5 implementations of that hook done in Drupal core, for example [`config_translation_entity_operation()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21config_translation%21config_translation.module/function/config_translation_entity_operation/9), [`content_translation_entity_operation()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_translation%21content_translation.module/function/content_translation_entity_operation/9), or [`field_ui_entity_operation()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field_ui%21field_ui.module/function/field_ui_entity_operation/9).
The code they use to get the URL vary from one implementation to the other. The simpler way to get a URL for a page created from a module you wrote, for which you know the page route, is calling [`Url::fromRoute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/9).

Comment: They all seem to use the linkTemplate thing that I'm having trouble grokking, where can I find documentation for that?

Comment: [Introduction to Entity API in Drupal 8 / Links](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/introduction-to-entity-api-in-drupal-8#s-links) gives some details. If you look at the annotation used for Drupal core content entities, you will see how their entity links are defined.

Comment: I ended up implementing a custom route using my modules routing.yml. I'm guessing there's some way to add custom "link templates" when you can't change the annotation but I didn't have time to dig into that.